# chechbox .checked error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a listview that I used an update panel in it and all codes is in update panel. I used a check box and an event for it that checks if checkbox is checked the textbox visibility should be true and dropdown list visibility should be false. but after checking checkbox the software break and show Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error. my asp.net codes:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upchk" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            ///
            <td><asp:Label ID="label17" CssClass="fasele" runat="server" Text="رشته : ">
                </asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                DataTextField="reshte" DataValueField="reshteId" AutoPostBack="True" 
                runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList></td>
            <td>

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" 
                EnableViewState="true" /> : افزودن رشته جدید</td>
            /////
        </ContentTemplate>  
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  EventName="checkedchanged" ControlID="CheckBox1" />
        </Triggers> 
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

my .cs codes:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)ListView1.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    TextBox txtrshte = (TextBox)ListView1.FindControl("TextBox8");
    DropDownList drpreshte = (DropDownList)ListView1.FindControl("DropDownList2");

    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        txtrshte.Visible = true;
        drpreshte.Visible = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14903094/2175939) question and its answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can find the parent `UpdatePanel` of the check box and find controls inside it like below:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    TextBox txtrshte = (TextBox)chk.Parent.FindControl("TextBox8");
    DropDownList drpreshte = (DropDownList)chk.Parent.FindControl("DropDownList2");

    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        txtrshte.Visible = true;
        drpreshte.Visible = false;

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I can see that your table structure has serious issue. You can't extend a table through an`UpdatePanel` this way. You have to move the update panel inside parent tables `<td>` and create a new table inside the `UpdatePanel`. Otherwise you will end up messing the rendered html, with doubled controls etc. Your corrected markup should look like this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <tr><td colspan="3">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upchk" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                ///
                <table><tr>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="label17" CssClass="fasele" runat="server" Text="رشته : ">
                        </asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        DataTextField="reshte" DataValueField="reshteId" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList></td>
                    <td>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                        oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" 
                        EnableViewState="true" /> : افزودن رشته جدید</td>
                </tr></table>
                /////
            </ContentTemplate>  
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  EventName="checkedchanged" ControlID="CheckBox1" />
            </Triggers> 
        </asp:UpdatePanel>    
        </td></tr>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I do this, and no error. but when I run the website and check the checkbox, a copy of edit create on top of orginal edit template. you can see my mean in this link :http://rogatech.somee.com/manage-darkhast-maghale.aspx  and you can see on sequential checking checkbox, the contet of last textboxs repeat!

Comment: That is because of wrong markup. You can't wrap part of a table with an `UpdatePanel`. See my edit.

Comment: great ! you right. now all the thing is ok. so thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, FindControl only searches at the parent control level.

What you need is a recursive findcontrol method that will find your child control:

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(this Control control, string id)
{
  if (control == null)
  {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("control")
  }

  foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
  {
      if (childControl.ID == id)
      {
         return childControl;
      }

      Control child = FindControlRecursive(ctl, id);
      if (child != null)
      {
          return child;
      }
}

return null;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Don't the elements get initialized on page load? (not my thing asp ... :) (ולמה אתה ער??)

Comment: thanks but I'm confused! what can I do really!? don't need to call this  function wherever?